# Nanosleep too long in any iOS simulator on macOS Sierra

Tags: ios, c, ios-simulator, sleep, macos-sierra

Nanosleep in the iOS simulator (running on MacOS Sierra with XCode 8.1 and 8.2beta) sleep around 5 times longer than the desired duration.

This doesn't happen on true iPhone 7 device or in a macOS Sierra app, only in the simulator.

Is it possible to have more accurate sleep duration in the simulator or is it a bug?

```
struct timespec request;
request.tv_sec = 0;
request.tv_nsec = 17000000; // 17ms

mach_timebase_info_data_t base;
mach_timebase_info(&base);

while (1) {
    uint64_t start, end, elapsed;
    start = mach_absolute_time();

    nanosleep(&request, NULL);

    end = mach_absolute_time();
    elapsed = (end - start) / base.denom;

    printf("Sleep = %f msec\n", elapsed * 1E-6);
}
```

Output:

```
    Sleep = 84.451425 msec  
    Sleep = 69.947846 msec  
    Sleep = 95.484521 msec  
    Sleep = 72.795438 msec  
    Sleep = 80.162972 msec  
    Sleep = 70.265713 msec  
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syscall ony gurantees that you'll be scheduled at some point after the requested duration.  You should not make any assumptions about how soon after.

That being said, there is an issue with Xcode 8.0-8.2 running on Sierra that is causing simulator processes to be scheduled at a lower priority than intended.  This is likely the reason you're seeing this difference in behavior between device and sim.

Comment: Jeremy and @russbishop, Thank you! :D I expected a priority problem too!

Comment: @Kris Please check Xcode 8.3 Beta and report back if that addresses your problem.  If not, please update with the output of `sudo taskinfo <pid>`

Comment: Fixed in Xcode 8.3 beta ! Thanks!! Actually we used a workaround for Xcode 8.2 simulator -> a loop with multiple small sleeps and time check.